# Jenkins Publish Over SSH Plugin on MacOS limits to 130MB and frezze

Tags: ssh, jenkins, sftp

In Jenkins `test` project i have in Execute shell:

`dd if=/dev/urandom of=ios_512MB bs=531628032 count=1`

and i have checked and configured `Send files or execute commands over SSH after the build runs`

When i run it i see:

```
Started by user X
Building remotely on ios in workspace /data/workspace/test
[test] $ /bin/sh -xe /var/folders/9b/s86tztx90bb9c_73gtynfzx80000gn/T/hudson8582983867531973712.sh
+ dd if=/dev/urandom of=ios_512MB bs=531628032 count=1

1+0 records in
1+0 records out
531628032 bytes transferred in 44.384345 secs (11977828 bytes/sec)
SSH: Connecting from host [jenkins2.local]
SSH: Connecting with configuration [jenkins.builds] ...
```

I see on Network traffic this connection, and its stops. On sftp i have:

```
ls -lh
-rw------- 1 10048 10047 130M Apr 16 09:56 ios_512MB
```

On windows/ubuntu all works well. How to fix it?

Comment: I would expect an IOException (or some kind of exception) if it happened, but did you make sure there's enough space on the destination machine?

Comment: File is generated by dd fine. When i send from ubuntu/windows worker file is sended. i have lot of free space.

Comment: I was referring to the machine where you are copying the file. Anyway, at this point your scenario is a bit unclear to me. Please provide a description of the entire process including where Jenkins is running, any slaves, what exactly the job is doing and where you are copying the 512MB generated file

Comment: This is test. In other project and more complicated process using xcode6 we create file (bigger than 150 MB), and we want to send it via sftp. I prefer to debug on a test project.

Jenkins server on Ubuntu, Windows, MacOS, Ubuntu slaves

Comment: I create test project to find where is error. What would you like to know? In new project i only generate file and sent it via sftp. And it's not working. On second iOS slave (without xcode6) file is locking at 300MB

Comment: Test or otherwise we need to understand your scenario before we can come up with suggestions, and this is why I asked for more details

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75404/discussion-between-mateusz-szymborski-and-morfic).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by Execute Shell:

```
echo "mkdir ${short}/${date}
mkdir ${short}/${date}/${RANDSTR}
put ${WORKSPACE}${location}${n}${format} ${short}/${date}/${RANDSTR}/
put ${WORKSPACE}${location}${n}.html ${short}/${date}/${RANDSTR}/" | sftp -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -P 2222 -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa jenkins.builds@sftp.example.com
```